# Duda con await_for

Tags: python, discord.py

Este es mi codigo, pero me gustaría saber como editar el mensaje de "cancelando atraco", ya que solo puedo editar el de "iniciando atraco"

```
@client.command()
async def banco(ctx):
    await ctx.send("¿Quieres iniciar un robo al banco?")
    await ctx.send("Di Si o No")

    def check(m):
        return m.content in ("si", "no")

    msg = await client.wait_for("message", check=check)

    msg = await ctx.send("Iniciando atraco" if msg.content == "si" else "Cancelando atraco :/.")
    await asyncio.sleep(5)
    await msg.edit(content='Ahora elige un arma.')
```

Comment: ¿Quieres decir que     `msg = await ctx.send("Iniciando robo" if msg.content == "si" else "Cancelando robo que viene la poli :/.")` no tiene efecto?

Comment: Si tiene efecto, pero quiero poderlo editar con msg.edit y no se como

Comment: Vale creo que tu problema real es que tanto si se inicia como se cancela el atraco el mensaje es siempre modificado posteriormente a 'Ahora elige un arma.' que supongo que solo debería aparecer tŕas el inicio. ¿Sería esto?

Comment: Algo asi, pero lo que busco es poder hacer que se editen diferente, convertir el else en otra variable

Comment: Utiliza un `if-else` normal en vez de escribirlo todo en una sola línea. `if msg.content == "si":` 1.- envía el mensaje de que el atraco se ha iniciado. 2.- espera 5 segundos. 3.- edita el mensaje diciendo que se elija un arma. //// `else:` 1.- envía el mensaje de que el atraco se ha cancelado.